# thymeleaf 3 spring 5 load css

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to configure `Spring5` and `Thymeleaf3` togheter.

I'm working on Eclipse, I build with `clean install` and run the app with `springboot:run`.

I've setup a controller and a couple of template and css but it seems that thymeleaf cannot find the css, in the browser it shows the template  (es. 'panda.html') without loading the css but if I open manually the .html the browser load also the .css .  What i need to add to my code?

this is the mapping

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

@Autowired
UtentiRepository utentiRepository;  

@GetMapping("/gab")
public String panda(Model model) {

return "panda";
}
```

and this is the template resolver

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templatecssResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/static/css/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".css");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templatecssResolver());
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    return templateEngine;
}

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    registry.viewResolver(resolver);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to override the `addResourceHandlers(..)` method of the you calls that implements the  `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` not as a bean (`SpringResourceTemplateResolver` )

SO  just add the overiding method

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
           .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
}
```

in your template use

```
<link href="<c:url value="/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

or using themleaf

```
<link th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />" rel="stylesheet">
```